# Grouping rows with a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and need to create a query that shows rows that fall within a date range.

My table is as follows:

```
ADM_ID    WH_PID     WH_IN_DATETIME    WH_OUT_DATETIME
```

My rules are:

- If the WH_OUT_DATETIME is on or within 24 hours of the WH_IN_DATETIME of another ADM_ID with the same WH_P_ID

I would like another column added to the results which identify the grouped value if possible as `EP_ID`.

e.g.

```
ADM_ID    WH_PID    WH_IN_DATETIME         WH_OUT_DATETIME
------    ------    --------------         ---------------
1         9         2014-10-12 00:00:00    2014-10-13 15:00:00
2         9         2014-10-14 14:00:00    2014-10-15 15:00:00
3         9         2014-10-16 14:00:00    2014-10-17 15:00:00
4         9         2014-11-20 00:00:00    2014-11-21 00:00:00
5         5         2014-10-17 00:00:00    2014-10-18 00:00:00
```

Would return rows with:

```
ADM_ID   WH_PID   EP_ID   EP_IN_DATETIME        EP_OUT_DATETIME       WH_IN_DATETIME        WH_OUT_DATETIME
------   ------   -----   -------------------   -------------------   -------------------   -------------------
1        9        1       2014-10-12 00:00:00   2014-10-17 15:00:00   2014-10-12 00:00:00   2014-10-13 15:00:00
2        9        1       2014-10-12 00:00:00   2014-10-17 15:00:00   2014-10-14 14:00:00   2014-10-15 15:00:00
3        9        1       2014-10-12 00:00:00   2014-10-17 15:00:00   2014-10-16 14:00:00   2014-10-17 15:00:00
4        9        2       2014-11-20 00:00:00   2014-11-20 00:00:00   2014-10-16 14:00:00   2014-11-21 00:00:00
5        5        1       2014-10-17 00:00:00   2014-10-18 00:00:00   2014-10-17 00:00:00   2014-10-18 00:00:00
```

The EP_OUT_DATETIME will always be the latest date in the group. Hope this clarifies a bit. 
This way, I can group by the EP_ID and find the EP_OUT_DATETIME and start time for any ADM_ID/PID that fall within.

---

Each should roll into the next, meaning that if another row has an WH_IN_DATETIME which follows on the WH_OUT_DATETIME of another for the same WH_PID, than that row's WH_OUT_DATETIME becomes the EP_OUT_DATETIME for all of the WH_PID's within that EP_ID.

I hope this makes some sense.

Thanks,
MR

Comment: Just out of curiosity, about how many rows are in this table?

Comment: @steven Can you please provide some feedback as to what was missing from my answer (or any / all of them) that did not fully meet your requirements such that the bounty was not awarded (it expired and so was auto-awarded at 50%). As far as I can tell from the question and comments on other answers, at least my answer, if not 1 or 2 others, did output the desired results. I am asking because a 200 point bounty indicates that this question is rather important to you but there is no feedback on answers suggested by me, Deepak, or Scott.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question does not specify that the solution be a "single" query ;-), here is another approach: using the "quirky update" feature dealy, which is updating a variable at the same time you update a column. Breaking down the complexity of this operation, I create a scratch table to hold the piece that is the hardest to calculate: the `EP_ID`. Once that is done, it gets joined into a simple query and provides the window with which to calculate the `EP_IN_DATETIME` and `EP_OUT_DATETIME` fields.

The steps are:

1. Create the scratch table
2. Seed the scratch table with all of the `ADM_ID` values -- this lets us do an UPDATE as all of the rows already exist.
3. Update the scratch table
4. Do the final, simple select joining the scratch table to the main table

**The Test Setup**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #Table
(
   ADM_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   WH_PID INT NOT NULL,
   WH_IN_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
   WH_OUT_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Table VALUES (1, 9, '2014-10-12 00:00:00', '2014-10-13 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES (2, 9, '2014-10-14 14:00:00', '2014-10-15 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES (3, 9, '2014-10-16 14:00:00', '2014-10-17 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES (4, 9, '2014-11-20 00:00:00', '2014-11-21 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES (5, 5, '2014-10-17 00:00:00', '2014-10-18 00:00:00');
```

**Step 1: Create and Populate the Scratch Table**

```
CREATE TABLE #Scratch
(
   ADM_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   EP_ID INT NOT NULL
   -- Might need WH_PID and WH_IN_DATETIME fields to guarantee proper UPDATE ordering
);

INSERT INTO #Scratch (ADM_ID, EP_ID)
   SELECT ADM_ID, 0
   FROM   #Table;
```

Alternate scratch table structure to ensure proper update order (since "quirky update" uses the order of the Clustered Index, as noted at the bottom of this answer):

```
CREATE TABLE #Scratch
(
   WH_PID INT NOT NULL,
   WH_IN_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
   ADM_ID INT NOT NULL,
   EP_ID INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Scratch (WH_PID, WH_IN_DATETIME, ADM_ID, EP_ID)
   SELECT WH_PID, WH_IN_DATETIME, ADM_ID, 0
   FROM   #Table;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_Scratch]
   ON #Scratch (WH_PID, WH_IN_DATETIME, ADM_ID);
```

**Step 2: Update the Scratch Table** using a local variable to keep track of the prior value

```
DECLARE @EP_ID INT; -- this is used in the UPDATE

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
         t1.*,
         t2.WH_OUT_DATETIME AS [PriorOut],
         t2.ADM_ID AS [PriorID],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.WH_PID ORDER BY t1.WH_IN_DATETIME)
                AS [RowNum]
  FROM   #Table t1
  LEFT JOIN #Table t2
         ON t2.WH_PID = t1.WH_PID
        AND t2.ADM_ID <> t1.ADM_ID
        AND t2.WH_OUT_DATETIME >= (t1.WH_IN_DATETIME - 1)
        AND t2.WH_OUT_DATETIME < t1.WH_IN_DATETIME
  ORDER BY t1.WH_PID, t1.WH_IN_DATETIME
)
UPDATE sc
SET    @EP_ID = sc.EP_ID = CASE
                               WHEN cte.RowNum = 1 THEN 1
                               WHEN cte.[PriorOut] IS NULL THEN (@EP_ID + 1)
                               ELSE @EP_ID
                        END
FROM   #Scratch sc
INNER JOIN cte
        ON cte.ADM_ID = sc.ADM_ID
```

**Step 3: Select Joining the Scratch Table**

```
SELECT tab.ADM_ID,
       tab.WH_PID,
       sc.EP_ID,
       MIN(tab.WH_IN_DATETIME) OVER (PARTITION BY tab.WH_PID, sc.EP_ID)
           AS [EP_IN_DATETIME],
       MAX(tab.WH_OUT_DATETIME) OVER (PARTITION BY tab.WH_PID, sc.EP_ID)
           AS [EP_OUT_DATETIME],
       tab.WH_IN_DATETIME,
       tab.WH_OUT_DATETIME
FROM   #Table tab
INNER JOIN #Scratch sc
    ON sc.ADM_ID = tab.ADM_ID
ORDER BY tab.ADM_ID;
```

**Resources**

- MSDN page for [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

  look for "@variable = column = expression"
- [Performance Analysis of doing Running Totals](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2011/08/running-totals-in-denali-ctp3/) (not exactly the same thing as here, but not too far off)

  This blog post does mention:

  - PRO: this method is generally pretty fast
  - CON: "The order of the UPDATE is controlled by the order of the clustered index". This behavior might rule out using this method depending on circumstances. But in this particular case, if the `WH_PID` values are not at least grouped together naturally via the ordering of the clustered index and ordered by `WH_IN_DATETIME`, then those two fields just get added to the scratch table and the PK (with implied clustered index) on the scratch table becomes `(WH_PID, WH_IN_DATETIME, ADM_ID)`.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using `exists` in a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table t2
                          where t2.WH_P_ID = t.WH_P_ID and
                                t2.ADM_ID = t.ADM_ID and
                                t.WH_OUT_DATETIME between t2.WH_IN_DATETIME and dateadd(day, 1, t2.WH_OUT_DATETIME)
                         )
             then 1 else 0
        end) as TimeFrameFlag
from table t;
```

Comment: Do you have a more comphrensive answer? This just flags immediate ones that fall within the range. Something that demonstrates a progressive inclusion of rows is needed

Comment: @Steven . . . I have no idea what you are really asking for.  The question has changed multiple times since I answered.  I was pretty sure this addressed the original question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query :

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT t1.ADM_ID AS EP_ID,*
         FROM   @yourtable t1
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM   @yourtable t2
                            WHERE  t1.WH_PID = t2.WH_PID
                                   AND t1.ADM_ID <> t2.ADM_ID
                                   AND Abs(Datediff(HH, t1.WH_OUT_DATETIME, t2.WH_IN_DATETIME)) <= 24)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT t2.EP_ID,t1.ADM_ID,t1.WH_PID,t1.WH_IN_DATETIME,t1.WH_OUT_DATETIME
         FROM   @yourtable t1
                JOIN cte t2
                  ON t1.WH_PID = t2.WH_PID
                     AND t1.ADM_ID <> t2.ADM_ID
                     AND Abs(( Datediff(HH, t2.WH_IN_DATETIME, t1.WH_OUT_DATETIME) )) <= 24),
     cte_result
     AS (SELECT t1.*,Dense_rank() OVER ( partition BY wh_pid ORDER BY t1.WH_PID, ISNULL(t2.EP_ID, t1.ADM_ID)) AS EP_ID
         FROM   @yourtable t1
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ADM_ID,
                                                 EP_ID
                                 FROM   cte) t2
                             ON t1.ADM_ID = t2.ADM_ID)
SELECT ADM_ID,WH_PID,EP_ID,Min(WH_IN_DATETIME)OVER(partition BY wh_pid, ep_id) AS [EP_IN_DATETIME],Max(WH_OUT_DATETIME)OVER(partition BY wh_pid, ep_id) AS [EP_OUT_DATETIME],
       WH_IN_DATETIME,
       WH_OUT_DATETIME
FROM   cte_result
ORDER  BY ADM_ID
```

I assumed these things :

- Those rows which follow your rule, are a `group`.
- `min(WH_IN_DATETIME)` of the group will be shown in `EP_IN_DATETIME` column for all rows belong to that group. Similarly, `max(WH_OUT_DATETIME)` of the group will be shown in `EP_IN_DATETIME` column for all rows belong to that group.
- `EP_ID` will be assigned to groups of each `WH_PID` separately.
- One thing which is not justified by your question that how `EP_OUT_DATETIME` and `WH_IN_DATETIME` of 4th row become `2014-11-20 00:00:00` and `2014-10-16 14:00:00` respectively. Assuming that it is a typo and it should be `2014-11-21 00:00:00.000` and `2014-11-20 00:00:00.000`.

Explaination :

First CTE `cte` will return the possible groups based on your rule. Second CTE `cte_result` will assign `EP_ID` to groups. In the last, you can select `min(WH_IN_DATETIME)` and `Max(WH_OUT_DATETIME)` in partitions of `wh_pid, ep_id`.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41219)

Comment: Nice answer!  There is one case that it doesn't handle currently, which is if the last row of a EP_ID group has a `WH_IN_DATETIME` and `WH_OUT_DATETIME` that are within 24 hrs of each other for that same ADM_ID, then it causes all of those rows to have different EP_ID groupings.  Example: on your SQLFiddle, change ADM_ID 3 to have an WH_OUT_DATETIME time of '2014-10-17 12:00:00' instead and you will see the bug.  To fix, just add `AND t1.ADM_ID <> t2.ADM_ID` within the where clause of the NOT EXISTS section of `cte`.

Comment: @BateTech Thank you so much for looking it thoroughly. I update the answer as well as sql fiddle  with your suggestions. I should have tested it more, my bad.

Comment: Hi do you have any suggestions for combating recursion errors? I have maxed out the recursion and the cte doesn't work. I've tried a few things including using a cursor to do each pid individually. The max count I found for each pid is 9. If I disable recursion, it runs for a very long time (I stopped it after 16 mins).

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another alternative... which may miss your results still.

I agree with @NoDisplayName that there appears to be an error in your ADM_ID 5 output, the 2 OUT dates should match - at least that seems logical to me. I can't understand why you would want an out date to ever be showing an in date value, but of course there could be a good reason. :)

Also, the wording of your question makes it sound like this is just a part of the problem and that you may take this output to then further. I'm not sure what you are really aiming for, but I've broken the query below up into 2 CTEs and you may find your final information in the 2nd CTE (as it sounds like you want to group the data back together).

Here's the complete structure & query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a2cc/1)

```
-- The Cross Join ensures we always have a pair of first and last time pairs
-- The left join matches all overlapping combinations, 
-- allowing the where clause to restrict to just the first and last
-- These first/last pairs are then grouped in the first CTE
-- Data is restricted in the second CTE
-- The final select is then quite simple
With GroupedData AS (
    SELECT
        (Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY t1.WH_PID, t1.WH_IN_DATETIME) - 1) / 2 Grp,
         t1.WH_IN_DATETIME, t1.WH_OUT_DATETIME, t1.WH_PID
    FROM yourtable t1 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS [First] UNION SELECT 1) SetOrder
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable t2
        ON t1.WH_PID = t2.WH_PID
        AND ((DATEADD(d,1,t1.WH_OUT_DATETIME) BETWEEN t2.WH_IN_DATETIME AND t2.WH_OUT_DATETIME AND [First] = 0)
             OR (DATEADD(d,1,t2.WH_OUT_DATETIME) BETWEEN t1.WH_IN_DATETIME AND t1.WH_OUT_DATETIME AND [First] = 1))
    WHERE t2.WH_PID IS NULL
), RestrictedData AS (
    SELECT WH_PID, MIN(WH_IN_DATETIME) AS WH_IN_DATETIME, MAX(WH_OUT_DATETIME) AS WH_OUT_DATETIME
    FROM GroupedData
    GROUP BY Grp, WH_PID
)
SELECT yourtable.ADM_ID, yourtable.WH_PID, RestrictedData.WH_IN_DATETIME AS EP_IN_DATETIME, RestrictedData.WH_OUT_DATETIME AS EP_OUT_DATETIME, yourtable.WH_IN_DATETIME, yourtable.WH_OUT_DATETIME
FROM RestrictedData
INNER JOIN yourtable
    ON RestrictedData.WH_PID = yourtable.WH_PID
    AND yourtable.WH_IN_DATETIME BETWEEN RestrictedData.WH_IN_DATETIME AND RestrictedData.WH_OUT_DATETIME
ORDER BY yourtable.ADM_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Left Outer Join` and `DateDiff` Function should help you to filter the records. Finally Use `Window Function` to create `GroupID's`

```
create table #test 
(ADM_ID int,WH_PID int,WH_IN_DATETIME DATETIME,WH_OUT_DATETIME  DATETIME)

INSERT #test
VALUES ( 1,9,'2014-10-12 00:00:00','2014-10-13 15:00:00'),
       (2,9,'2014-10-14 14:00:00','2014-10-15 15:00:00'),
       (3,9,'2014-10-16 14:00:00','2014-10-17 15:00:00'),
       (1,10,'2014-10-16 14:00:00','2014-10-17 15:00:00'),
       (2,10,'2014-10-18 14:00:00','2014-10-19 15:00:00')

SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition by a.WH_PID ORDER BY a.WH_IN_DATETIME) Group_Id,
       a.WH_PID,
       a.WH_IN_DATETIME,
       b.WH_OUT_DATETIME
FROM   #test a
       LEFT JOIN #test b
              ON a.WH_PID = b.WH_PID
                 AND a.ADM_ID <> b.ADM_ID
where  Datediff(hh, a.WH_OUT_DATETIME, b.WH_IN_DATETIME)BETWEEN 0 AND 24
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Group_Id    WH_PID  WH_IN_DATETIME          WH_OUT_DATETIME
--------    ------  ----------------------- -----------------------
1           9       2014-10-12 00:00:00.000 2014-10-15 15:00:00.000
2           9       2014-10-14 14:00:00.000 2014-10-17 15:00:00.000
1           10      2014-10-16 14:00:00.000 2014-10-19 15:00:00.000
```

Comment: there should be one row per group id with the min IN time and max OUT time

Comment: @Steven - What if the `WH_PID` is different.

Comment: Each group should be unique per PID. The grouping is by PID, ADM_ID and date range

Comment: Doesnt quite work when there is only one row for an adm_id and pid: see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0e99a/1/0

Comment: @Steven - yes dude you are right so what has to come in that case tell me i can fix it.

Comment: This answer is now outdated, sorry

Comment: @Steven -NOW Your expected output is totally confusing